# can you help resolve this issue?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am writing code to get a list of patients and prescribe drug for any of the patient selected. I am using javascript for the code. I needed to fetch the data with fetch api and then loop them over the select html element. the fetch api works well, fetches the data but however, the map function only returns the last member in the list.

```
const getData = async(url) => {
  response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
  });
  return response;
};

function setPxt(data) {
  const pxtbox = document.querySelector(".pxt");

  const pxtselect = document.createElement("div");
  let pxt = {};
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    pxt = e.target.value;
  };
  const form = document.querySelector(".drugs");
  const legend = document.createElement("div");
  legend.innerHTML = `<p>Prescribe Drug for ${data.firstname}</p>`;
  form.append(legend);
  const selected = document.querySelector("input");
  selected.type = "text";
  selected.value = pxt.id;
  selected.name = "pxt_id";
  form.append(selected);
  data.map((pxt) => {
    pxtselect.innerHTML = ` 
    <select key =${pxt.id}> 
     <option value=${pxt.id}>${pxt.firstname}${pxt.lastname}</option>
    </select>
    `;
    pxtbox.append(pxtselect);
  });

}

function setData() {
  const url = "http://localhost:8000/patients/";
  getData(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data) {
        setPxt(data);
        console.log(data);
      } else if (!data) {
        const box = document.querySelector(".pxt");
        box.innerHTML = `<p>No Patients Data</p>`;
      }
    });
}

setData();
```

[you will notice the select at the top part of the image with only one member of the list I fetched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1Hv0.png)

Comment: in your `.map` you do `pxtselect.innerHTML = ` so, only the last "patient" will be shown as an option

Comment: See [ask].  "Can you help?" is not a useful question title - please [edit] to something meaningful

Comment: `pxtbox.append(pxtselect);` will *move* the element each time - so you only get one.  Move the `const pxtselect = document.createElement("div");` to *inside* the `data.map((pxt) =>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map function returns an array, in this case an array of HTML snippets aka. the option elements. This array can be turned into a string by applying the join function with an empty string as parameter.

```js
let pxtselect = document.forms.form01.pxtselect;

let data = [
  {id:1,firstname:'John',lastname:'Doe'},
  {id:2,firstname:'Jane',lastname:'Doe'}
];

pxtselect.innerHTML = data.map((pxt) => {
  return `<option value=${pxt.id}>${pxt.firstname}${pxt.lastname}</option>`;
}).join('');

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target;
  console.log(form.pxtselect.value);
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
    <select name="pxtselect"></select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

### Update

On how to get the value of a select element: You can get the select element by it's name on the form. And then the value property has the value of the selected option: `form.pxtselect.value`.

Comment: Please do you know how I can always get the value of a selected option, cos regardless of what I do I always get the last option as value even though all items are displayed

Comment: @Pogbogu I updated my answer with an example of how to get the value of the selected option in the select element.